# cat has a swollen area after a cat attack

Tags: cats, health, injury

My cat got into a fight with another cat and ever since that day, she's been acting off. The day after the fight she slept in the same chair for the whole day (over 14 hours). I also noticed that she is purring way more, so when you go to pet her, she'll purr immediately. She has not been active and does not show as much of an interest in food.

I also found a swollen area on her lower back, the part that is right above the base of the tail. It was swollen for about a week and she wouldn't let me touch it, like she would meow and move, right away. This morning, i noticed some pus-like white residue on that section of her fur.

Is my cat alright? Will this swollen area heal by itself? Is there anything I should know about this?

Answer (score 4):

Cats use purring both as a sign of pleasure, but also more relevant to this situation to soothe themselves when they are in pain or is uncomfortable.

This combined with the lack of an appetite alone would indicate that it's time to go to the vet for a checkup, the bump with pus coming out of it absolutely guarantees it.

Pus would indicate an infection, and while there is a chance it will heal by itself there is no guarantee, and it might do long term damage.

So TLDR: Time for a trip to the vet!

Comment: take your cat to the vet so the absess can be emptied and flushed out it is a fairly easy operation and dont need to cost a lot,normaly there is no need for medication  after the wound have been treated.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an abscess for sure. Drainage and a shunt are indicated with follow-up antibiotics. Vet visit is NECESSARY.

Abscesses are deep, purulent, puncture wounds that need to heal from the inside out, thus the shunt. The skin surface will close and seal in bacterial/viral infection and could potentially kill your cat. The swelling and pus are indicators of the infection.
Please take your cat to the vet immediately. She is giving every indication she needs veterinary attention ASAP.